# Was this resource question closed because of the word "best?"

Tags: discussion, on-topic, specific-question

I found this question: [The best tool for drawing on (Google) Maps](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/116904/the-best-tool-for-drawing-on-google-maps)

It's been closed as POB.  Was that because of the OP's use of the word "best?"

I thought software recommendations were allowed so long as they [directly relate to worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and it would seem that something that could annotate Google for an alternative history would be on-topic.

Answer (score 5):

In a word, yes.

I cast the third (and, in this case, binding) close vote as Primarily Opinion-Based. The reason was indeed the use of the word "best", because "best" is a surprisingly non-descriptive word. It doesn't describe what other features or abilities the OP is looking for, and doesn't give a way to rank one tool above another. That's what we need to avoid falling into the POB hole.

I didn't comment on the question because a few people had already beaten me to it:

> [Hello, *Martin L*, and welcome to Worldbuilding.  This question is interesting but extremely opinion-based.  Perhaps you could edit to clarify exactly what would make one tool better than another?  Please visit our help center and take the tour to learn more about the site.  Have a nice day!](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/116904/the-best-tool-for-drawing-on-google-maps#comment358694_116904)

and

> [Agree with Gryphon. It would help reduce the "opinion based" complaint if you spelled out some parameters that you will require of the tool. What are your specific needs? (I won't have an answer, but as asked, you're bound to get "I like XYZ because..." answers that will not likely help you or anyone who reads your question in the future.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/116904/the-best-tool-for-drawing-on-google-maps#comment358741_116904)

Essentially, if the OP specified what other criteria they were looking for in this sort of tool, I'd be satisfied.

#### Update, 7/4/2018

The question has been reopened, after the improvements that were brought up were made. I think we can consider this a happy and successful ending.

Comment: Thanks!  My goal was to get a more definitive position to help the OP.  I appreciate taking the time to clarify.

Comment: I was the one who flagged the question as POB, and the one who wrote the first comment HDE quoted.  This answer pretty much sums up why I flagged the question, but I would like to add that, other than the completely unhelpful word "best", there were no criteria for what made any tool better than another, the defining mark of a POB question.